# Getting Errors after MySQL database import

Tags: magento2, database, import

I took a MySQL dump of my live website and imported the data to a fresh database for my development site.

However, only the homepage is working, other links bring an error

> **There has been an error processing your request Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.**

Below is the error report. Anyone who can assist?

> {"0":"Notice: Undefined index:  in /var/www/aslive/app/code/Magento/Developer/Model/View/Page/Config/RendererFactory.php on line 70","1":"#0 /var/www/aslive/app/code/Magento/Developer/Model/View/Page/Config/RendererFactory.php(70): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined index...', '/var/www/aslive...', 70, Array)\n#1 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page.php(159): Magento\Developer\Model\View\Page\Config\RendererFactory->create(Array)\n#2 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page.php(149): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->initPageConfigReader()\n#3 /var/www/aslive/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(14): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ReaderPool), Object(Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\BuilderFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool), Object(Magento\Developer\Model\View\Page\Config\RendererFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Page\Layout\Reader), 'Magento_Theme::...', false, NULL)\n#4 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(116): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context), Object(Magento\Framework\View\LayoutFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ReaderPool), Object(Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\BuilderFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool), Object(Magento\Developer\Model\View\Page\Config\RendererFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Page\Layout\Reader), 'Magento_Theme::...', false, NULL)\n#5 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)\n#6 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)\n#7 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Result/PageFactory.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)\n#8 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/View.php(74): Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory->create(true)\n#9 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\View->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\Config\Scope), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy), Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag))\n#10 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)\n#11 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...')\n#12 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(160): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')\n#13 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(246): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'view', 'Magento\\Framewo...')\n#14 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Framewo...', Array, Array)\n#15 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Framewo...', Array, Array)\n#16 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...')\n#17 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(160): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')\n#18 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(246): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'context', 'Magento\\Framewo...')\n#19 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Framewo...', Array, Array)\n#20 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\\Framewo...', Array, Array)\n#21 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)\n#22 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/ActionFactory.php(44): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...')\n#23 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Router/DefaultRouter.php(51): Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory->create('Magento\\Framewo...')\n#24 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController.php(95): Magento\Framework\App\Router\DefaultRouter->match(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#25 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#26 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#27 /var/www/aslive/app/code/Magento/Store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#28 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#29 /var/www/aslive/app/code/Magento/PageCache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#30 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#31 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#32 /var/www/aslive/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)\n#33 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n#34 /var/www/aslive/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()\n#35 /var/www/aslive/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()\n#36 /var/www/aslive/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))\n#37 {main}","url":"/axis/catalog/product/index/key/c065d4e1f5070487e85f9e2494250f74d4d6402723958923ef97dee27bdc1716/","script_name":"/index.php"}

Comment: Run this in your root to see the error on frontend 
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

Comment: setup:di:compile after setup:upgrade should fix this issue